# PHP script throws an impossible error - on one server, not on another

Tags: php, object, webserver

I suffer a little error and don't find a cue where to begin...

> [11-Oct-2012 22:01:45] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function
>   getVariableIndices() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/web1/html/inc/ProjectCache.php on line 545

Sound quite simple, but here is the code (with line numbers)

```
525 $itemData = $queryItems->fetchRows();
525 foreach ($questionData as $qData) {
526     $qp = QuestionPack::createWithData($qData, $itemData);
<snip>
538     $question = $qp->createGenerator(null);
539     if (!is_object($question)) {
540         trigger_error('Could not initialize generator ...', E_USER_WARNING);
541         continue;
542     }
543             
544     // Question variables
545     $vix = $question->getVariableIndices();
<snip>
597     $question->destroy();
598 }
```

The method createGenerator() should always return an object. I added the subsequent IF statement for debugging reasons - never knows if my thinking is completely wrong...

The destroy method sets some instance variables (references to other objects) null, so that the garbage collector won't stick in circular references.

This problem only occurs in exactly one of about 10.000 projects on a productive system (Debian, PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14). Using the same script and the same data from the database, I fail to replicate it on my Windows developer system (PHP 5.3.1).

I should note that hunderts of thousands of method calls are done before the script comes to this statement (about 14 sec. processing time, because a cache is initialized during this run).

My best explanation for now is that anywhere in the megabytes of PHP script I trigger a buffer overflow or mislead the garbage collector, so that the object is released although still in use. However, the error triggers always in the same project, always with the same line (and it moves with this statement, if I place other debugging code before). This sounds quite untypical for my ideas.

Restarting the webserver did (of course) not help. Dropping the previous cache file did not help, either. This is where I am stuck. Anyone else finds this weired? Anyone who has an idea where to start??

Thanks

BurninLeo

Comment: do a `var_dump($question)` in your error handler to see what it IS at that point. then start backtracking up the call tree to see where something's failing for that particular object so as to cause a non-object to be propagated.

Comment: Are you sure your factory method is returning what you expect it's returning?

Comment: I agree with Marc.  I would add that a more sure fire way to check your object is to use the instance keyword and make sure it fits the specific class or interface that you are expecting.

Comment: @Joshua: Is there something unsure about is_object?

Comment: @Marc B: That was a really good idea (no irony)! An error handler does not work for fatal error and the registered shutdown var_dump crashed together with the script. Collecting the var_dump() each time the method was called resulted in a text file which download I cancelled at 600 MB (and still growing). Still searching for a way to track down the variable contents, I added an IF statement. And this **reliably** avoids the script from crashing. As soon as I remove it, the crash is replicated. Here is the statement I added in line 543: `if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {}`. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have fixed a similar odd issue in php 5.3.2 by disabling the garbage collector via adding:
zend.enable_gc = Off
to php.ini. (and of course rebooting apache or whatever application server is parsing the php)

If that doesn't work I would suggest comparing your phpinfo() from a working server to the one with an issue. Preferably comparing linux to linux or windows to windows. Maybe something in the configuration will jump out at you.

I would also raise the error level to include notices.

Finally I would use gettype and get_class on $question when it's not an object to see what it IS. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Possibly call debug_backtrace as well when the error occurs. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Good luck!

Comment: Hi! The error level (of course) was already set to include notices and - according to is_object() the $question IS an object. Disabling the garbage collector is no option, as this would result in a stack size far beyond 100 MB. However, I think that the garbage collector is somehow the problem - and I do not know ehy it works differently (if it is) when I ask for a value from the $GLOBALS array...

Comment: Well, I don't know your exact php version or the situation but RAM is cheap and developer time isn't. :-) I'd extend your php memory limit to a stupid amount like 256 or 512mb and try it. Maybe search the php bug list under your specific version. Example GC bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48781